# React JS - Live clock update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a clock function that gets time and renders out the hours, minutes and seconds, and I'm trying to update the data on screen in real time, but for some reason my setInterval function isn't doing what I expect.

I thought react's render method is supposed to render data in real time. Do I need ajax for this? Can anyone offer some advice?

```
var CityRow = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    var currentdate = new Date();

    function getTime() {
      // get local time based on the UTC offset
      this.hours = currentdate.getUTCHours() + parseInt(this.props.UTCOffset);    

      // correct for number over 24, and negatives
      if( this.hours >= 24 ){ this.hours = this.hours - 24; }
      if( this.hours < 0   ){ this.hours = this.hours + 12; }

      // add leading zero, first convert hours to string
      this.hours = this.hours + "";
      if( this.hours.length == 1 ){ this.hours = "0" + this.hours; }

      // minutes are the same on every time zone
      this.minutes = currentdate.getUTCMinutes();

      // add leading zero, first convert hours to string
      this.minutes = this.minutes + "";
      if( this.minutes.length == 1 ){ this.minutes = "0" + this.minutes; }

      this.seconds = currentdate.getUTCSeconds();
    }

    window.setInterval(function () {
      getTime();
    }, 1000);

    return(
      <div className="city-row" ref="cityRow">
        <span className="city-time">{this.hours}:{this.minutes}:{this.seconds}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There seems to be a couple problems with your code. First is the closing div in the render function which causes your element to not even render.

Next you might want to take a look at state/props and React general lifecycle methods to get a better idea of program flow. The setInterval should be put in componentDidMount so its not called every time your component renders and creates a lot of timers. It also might help to put hours, minutes, and seconds as state so that way when these change your component re-renders automatically.

I modified your code below and put an example on jsfiddle. It does not print the seconds properly (just like in your getTime method) but hopefully it will give you a better idea of how logic should flow.

https://jsfiddle.net/rpg6t4uc/

```
var CityRow = React.createClass({
  setTime: function(){

    var currentdate = new Date();
    var hours = currentdate.getUTCHours() + parseInt(this.props.UTCOffset);    

      // correct for number over 24, and negatives
      if( hours >= 24 ){ hours -= 24; }
      if( hours < 0   ){ hours += 12; }

      // add leading zero, first convert hours to string
      hours = hours + "";
      if( hours.length == 1 ){ hours = "0" + hours; }

      // minutes are the same on every time zone
      var minutes = currentdate.getUTCMinutes();

      // add leading zero, first convert hours to string
      minutes = minutes + "";
      if( minutes.length == 1 ){ minutes = "0" + minutes; }

      seconds = currentdate.getUTCSeconds();
      console.log(hours, minutes, seconds)
      this.setState({
        hours: hours,
        minutes: minutes,
        seconds: seconds
      });
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.setTime();
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
     window.setInterval(function () {
      this.setTime();
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  },
  render: function() {

    return(
      <div className="city-row" ref="cityRow">
        <span className="city-time">{this.state.hours}:{this.state.minutes}:{this.state.seconds}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you! the data binding is what i was missing! the errant div is due to my having edited (stripped out) some code for this question and was my mistake. thanks again!

Comment: Great, that works. Only thing, unless you need the hours, minutes, seconds separate, I think it's better to build the time string in the `setTime()` function and save that in the state.

Answer (score 16):

The official React Docs describe exactly what you need (and even explains why you should do it as described):

[--> React Docs: State and Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

[Example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/amqdNA):

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

functional component

```
function Time() {

 const [time, setTime] = React.useState(new Date());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
     setTime(new Date());
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

 return <span>{time.toLocaleString("en-US", {

  dateStyle: "full",
  timeStyle: "medium",
    hour12: false,
  
})} </span>;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update of "TheSchecke" answer to show UTC date on format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss":

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    const ISOStringDate = this.state.date.toISOString();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>UTC Time:</h1>
            <h2>{ISOStringDate.substring(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')}</h2>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
    
   state ={time:null}
    
    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({time:new Date().toLocaleTimeString()})}, 1000)
       }

    render() {
            return (
            <div className="time">
                The time is: {this.state.time}
            </div>
             );
         }
  }

  ReactDOM.render( 
      <Clock />,
      document.getElementById('root') );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Clock extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            dateClass: new Date()
        }

        this.time = this.state.dateClass.toLocaleTimeString();
        this.hourMin = this.time.length === 10? this.time.slice(0) : this.time.slice(0,5);
    }

    setTime = () => {
        this.setState({
            dateClass: new Date()
        })
        this.time = this.state.dateClass.toLocaleTimeString();
        this.hourMin = this.time.length === 10? this.time.slice(0) : this.time.slice(0,5);
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        setInterval(this.setTime, 1000)
    }
    
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.hourMin}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Clock;
```

Hey, I have more simple approach.